# For loop as function in R

Tags: r, function, loops

How to include a loop in a function?

EntEC1 is df has 12 rows and 5 variables.

A loop is working by itself:

```
for(i in 1:11){
aa <- cor(as.numeric(EntEC1[i,2:5]),as.numeric(EntEC1[i+1,2:5]))
EntEC1$cor[i] <- aa
}
```

But it is not running when I try to create a function call Co

```
Co <- function(x){
for(i in 1:11){
aa <- cor(as.numeric(x[i,2:5]),as.numeric(x[i+1,2:5]))
x$cor[i] <- aa
}
}
Co(EntEC1)
```

It is not working. The idea is to replace the EntEC1 in the loop with function x.

Comment: try using `<<-` instead of `<-`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Andre Elrico, you can change `x$cor[i] <- aa` to `x$cor[i] <<- aa`.

However, the problem with your function is that it does not return any result. To do that, you should change as follows:

```
Co <- function(x){
for(i in 1:11){
aa <- cor(as.numeric(x[i,2:5]),as.numeric(x[i+1,2:5]))
x$cor[i] <- aa
}
return(x)
}
```

Now, to replace your data frame with the result, you should: `EntEC1 <- Co(EntEC1)`

`Co(EntEC1)` would only show you the results, without saving it.

Comment: THANK YOU,Ricardo!! It works. I added return(x) at the end of the code, it gives what I want. However, could you explain a little more, why adding return x is necessary for a function? while I don't need it if I use loop directly?

Comment: Every function should return something, and you have to tell it exactly what to return. If you don't, it will run the code, and return nothing. What happens inside a function are deleted after it runs, except for what you return.